# Python parallelism with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor (or multiprocessing.Pool) and AsyncIO

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-3.12

Currently, I'm working on a project that listens to every API request, perform checks on it and sends it back. Sadly, API managed to overload my single threaded AsyncIO and multi-threading attempts, but CPU never reached even 20% of load.

So my idea is to use multiprocessing and fully load (70-90%) the CPU. Best way (I thought) was to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.Pool` as I could simply set `max_workers` and `max_tasks_per_child` and with power of `asyncio` and handle as many requests as CPU could possibly handle. But I failed.

My current problem is with process creation inside my custom Queue system. To be exact, I don't exactly know how to create an isolated process that would:

- spawn an `asyncio` loop
- run async function (with 3s timeout) that has `asyncio.TaskGroup()`
- run all tasks
- return data

basically, I want to create a copy of required check functions (Queue system provides them), run them in the **isolated** process and return data.

Here is the `add_queue` method:

```py
async def add_queue(self, function: str, id: int | None, **kwargs) -> None:
    functions: tuple | None = self.filter.get(function)
    process_executor: syscon.concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor = self.CONNECTOR.process_executor

    if not functions:
        self.logger.log(level="DEBUG", message=f"@Queue | No match found for {function}.")
    elif guild_id is None:
        self.logger.log(level="DEBUG", message=f"@Queue | No ID found in {function} request.")
    elif process_executor is None:
        self.logger.log(level="ERROR", message="ProcessPoolExecutor does NOT exist!")
    else:
        try:
            self.logger.log(level="DEBUG", message=f"@Queue | Submitting task to ProcessPoolExecutor.")
            self.process_executor.submit(self.process_event_runner, functions=functions, id=id, **kwargs) 
        except Exception as error:
            self.logger.log(level="ERROR", message=f"@Queue | {type(error).__name__}: {error}")
```

and the method that gets called:

```py
def process_event_runner(self, functions: tuple, id: int, **inputedargs) -> None:
    self.logger.log(level="DEBUG", message=f"@Queue.process_event_runner | Runner executing.")
    event_loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(async_task_worker(functions=functions, loop=event_loop, id=id, **inputedargs), timeout=3))
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        self.logger.log(level="WARNING", message=f"@Queue.process_event_runner | Task timed out. Terminating.")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        self.logger.log(level="WARNING", message=f"@Queue.process_event_runner | Task cancelled. Terminating.")
    except ExceptionGroup as groupError:
        self.logger.log(level="ERROR", message=f"@Queue.process_event_runner | Exception Group Error: {', '.join([f'SubE {num}: {exception}' for num, exception in enumerate(groupError.exceptions, 1)])}")
    except Exception as error:
        self.logger.log(level="ERROR", message=f"@Queue.process_event_runner | {type(error).__name__}: {error}")
    
    async def async_task_worker(functions, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop, id: int, **inputedargs):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)     
        
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
            tasks: list[asyncio.Task] = [group.create_task(func(**inputedargs)) for func in functions]
        return True
```

Both of these methods provided, are inside a class named `Queue`.

After running this, nothing happened. Figured out that `.submit()` did not execute provided function, but executed `main.py` which only has the whole system start-up. *Queue system is in `src.core.transmitters.queue`.*

How can I create an isolated processes, that creates a copy of the runner function (`process_event_runner`) and all the other functions that are defined inside a tuple in `functions` variable and runs them? And still have a way to limit `workers` and a way to use `asyncio`? Is it even possible?

For any questions on how the whole system works, feel free to ask in the comments and I will try my best to answer them.

As asked by the Michael in the comments, here is the full traceback of the circular import error that I get when trying to import the specified function (process_event_runner) in `main.py` before `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\RedSecurity\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.core.transmitters.queue import process_event_runner
  File "d:\Projects\RedSecurity\src\core\transmitters\queue.py", line 3, in <module>
    import src.sysConnector as syscon
  File "d:\Projects\RedSecurity\src\sysConnector.py", line 9, in <module>
    from src.core.transmitters.queue import Queue
ImportError: cannot import name 'Queue' from partially initialized module 'src.core.transmitters.queue' (most likely due to a circular import) (d:\Projects\RedSecurity\src\core\transmitters\queue.py)
```

The loader is after the `if __main__...` rule and start method is set to `spawn`. Like this:

```
from src.core.transmitters.queue import process_event_runner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import discord, sys, aiohttp, os, json, platform, glob, concurrent.futures, multiprocessing
    sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
    from discord.ext import commands
    import src.system.colors as colors
    import src.sysConnector as syscon
    import src.setup as setup
    
    class Bot(commands.AutoShardedBot):
        #enabling all intents and setting up command_prefix
        #initializing bot (intents, shards, prefix..)
        def __init__(self, connector: syscon.SysConnector, setup: setup.Setup) -> None:
            super().__init__(command_prefix="> ", intents=discord.Intents.all(), shard_count=1, help_command=None, max_messages=10000)
            ...
```

Comment: If this is executed on Windows (or MacOS, I think) the start method of subprocesses is "spawn". Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) about the special requirements of this method?

Comment: I have. Both multiprocessing and ProcessPoolExecutor. There are difference between Linux and Windows systems, but honestly, couldn't find the solution/understand the docs.

Comment: One important thing is to put the active code in `main.py` (usually everything except imports and definitions of classes, functions and constants) in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` block to prevent its execution when a subprocess is spawned.

Comment: Its kind of impossible for me to import them, as it triggers the `circular import error`. Any other way of spawning? I'm currently using Windows, but I do have plans to switch to Linux

Comment: What exactly is the problem with import? Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) as well as the related code in the question.

Comment: Added the traceback and the start of the `main.py` in the question. (it has over 150 lines of code, so that's why I didn't add the whole code).

Comment: Importing a method of a class separately isn't possible anyway and not necessary for multiprocessing.